# RegEx request - Remove characters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I would like to remove everything before the file name so I am using this regex : `(/^.*[\\\/]/)` and it works well.

```
// pseudo-code
var original = 'C:\this\is\my\path\file.jsgz';
var result = original.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
```

And it works. But I also would like to remove the *gz* at the end but I don't want to remove all occurrence of *gz*, only the last which is part of the extension.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your regex like this:

```
var result = original.replace(/^.*\\|gz$/g, '');
//=> file.js
```

This will remove string upto `/` from start (greedy) or `gz` at the end.